# Google App Engine upload fail

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am following a turorial and tried to deploy a simple app through Google App Engine,but it failed with following error message.I tried numerous times,but still the same issue.

Can anyone help on this?.

```
2014-04-01 18:19:50 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=alexkutty19@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', u'C:\\Users\\SUBIN\\Desktop\\LEARN PYTHON\\hfwwhapp-hrd']"
06:19 PM Application: hfwwgapp-hrd; version: 3
06:19 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:20 PM 
Starting update of app: hfwwgapp-hrd, version: 3
06:20 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for alexkutty19@gmail.com: 2014-04-01 18:21:29,681 ERROR appcfg.py:2229 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5053, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5044, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2730, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4725, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3525, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3578, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3461, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2222, in DoUpload
    self.rpcserver, self.config, self.error_fh)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 468, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config, error_fh))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 438, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 387, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
2014-04-01 18:21:29 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Comment: This is not enough.. can you show us your `app.yaml?`

Comment: Hey...i fixed it.... It was because of registered app name and app name(in .yaml) mismatch....thaanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gues you have to upload using this command:

```
appcfg.py update guestbook/
```

Nothing better than following the official guide:
[google dev](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading)